# Presenting a HTML website offline without a 'folder structure'

Tags: html, offlineapps

I have written a small manual in HTML that I would like others to be able to use. Is there a way that I can 'package' the website folder structure into one file so that nobody has to worry about finding the index.html page?

Answer (score 0):

MHTML, short for MIME HTML, is a web page archive format used to combine resources that are typically represented by external links (such as images, Flash animations, Java applets, and audio files) with HTML code into a single file.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML).

Comment: Thanks for your answer janzoner, it sounds like it's exactly what I need, but IE isn't producing what I expected. I open my home page, and save it as a .mht, and I get a .mht file of my home page, but all of the links lead me to the original .html pages! Am I doing something wrong? I get that the .mht file may bundle all of the elements on one .html page into one file, but I need to have all of the .html pages on my site bundled into one file.

Comment: @YoungPadawan Sorry, I don't have personal experience with mhtml. Maybe this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2mht/) could help you.

Comment: thanks, I had seen that, but I need something that doesn't require downloading more software (like offline explorer). Maybe I should try turning it into a pdf, although that would take the charm out of it.